# How to use drawInRect:withAttributes: instead of drawAtPoint:forWidth:withFont:fontSize:lineBreakMode:baselineAdjustment: in iOS 7

Tags: ios, nsstring, ios7

This method is deprecated in iOS 7.0:

```
drawAtPoint:forWidth:withFont:fontSize:lineBreakMode:baselineAdjustment:
```

Now use `drawInRect:withAttributes:` instead.

I can't find the attributeName of fontSize and baselineAdjustment.

**Edit**

Thanks @Puneet answer.

Actually, I mean if there doesn't have these key, how to implement this method in iOS 7?

Like below method:

```
+ (CGSize)drawWithString:(NSString *)string atPoint:(CGPoint)point forWidth:(CGFloat)width withFont:(UIFont *)font fontSize:(CGFloat)fontSize
           lineBreakMode:(IBLLineBreakMode)lineBreakMode
      baselineAdjustment:(UIBaselineAdjustment)baselineAdjustment {
    if (iOS7) {
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, width, CGFLOAT_MAX);

        NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
        paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = lineBreakMode;

        NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: font, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle};

        [string drawInRect:rect withAttributes:attributes];

        size = CGSizeZero;
    }
    else {
        size = [string drawAtPoint:point forWidth:width withFont:font fontSize:fontSize lineBreakMode:lineBreakMode baselineAdjustment:baselineAdjustment];
    }
    return size;
}
```

I don't know how to pass `fontSize` and `baselineAdjustment` to

`attributes` dictionary.

e.g.

`NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName` key should pass a `NSNumer` to it, but the `baselineAdjustment` is `Enum`.

Isn't there have other way to pass the two variables?

Comment: The constants are listed in the docs for the UIKit additions to `NSAttributedString`.

Comment: Thanks, I also know this, but I don't konw how to implement this method in iOS 7.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use `NSDictionary` and apply attributes like this:

```
NSFont *font = [NSFont fontWithName:@"Palatino-Roman" size:14.0];

NSDictionary *attrsDictionary =

[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              font, NSFontAttributeName,
                              [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName, nil];
```

Use `attrsDictionary` as argument.

Refer:  [Attributed String Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/AttributedStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000036i)

Refer: [Standard Attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/AttributedStrings/Articles/standardAttributes.html)

**SWIFT:**
IN **String** drawInRect is not available but we can use **NSString** instead:

```
let font = UIFont(name: "Palatino-Roman", size: 14.0)
let baselineAdjust = 1.0
let attrsDictionary =  [NSFontAttributeName:font, NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName:baselineAdjust] as [NSObject : AnyObject]
let str:NSString = "Hello World"
str.drawInRect(CGRectZero, withAttributes: attrsDictionary)
```

Comment: Please read the question again. The OP is looking for two specific attribute keys.

Comment: How can I make string multi line?

Answer (score 34):

It is a little more complicated than before and you cannot use a minimum font size, but have to use minimum font scale factor. There is also a bug in the iOS SDK, which breaks it for most use cases (see notes at the bottom). Here is what you have to do:

```
// Create text attributes
NSDictionary *textAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0]};

// Create string drawing context
NSStringDrawingContext *drawingContext = [[NSStringDrawingContext alloc] init];
drawingContext.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5; // Half the font size

CGRect drawRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 100.0);
[string drawWithRect:drawRect
             options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
          attributes:textAttributes
             context:drawingContext];
```

**Notes:**

- There seems to be a bug in the iOS 7 SDK at least up to version 7.0.3: If you specify a custom font in the attributes, the miniumScaleFactor is ignored. If you pass nil for the attributes, the text is scaled correctly.
- The `NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin` option is important. It tells the text drawing system, that the drawing rect's origin should be at the top left corner.
- There is no way to set the baselineAdjustment using the new method. You would have to do that yourself by calling `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:` first and then adjusting the rect before you pass it to `drawWithRect:options:attributes:context`.

Comment: Much better answer. Quick note, you can adjust the baseline with NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName, but only negative values to shift the text down will work. Positive values to shift the text up are clamped down to zero.