# drawAtPoint deprecated iOS 7

Tags: ios, deprecated

I have the follow code:

```
  - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    [super drawRect:rect];

    float imageHeight = self.image.size.height;

    float imageWidth = self.image.size.width;
    float ratio = imageHeight/imageWidth;
    if(imageHeight> MAX_IMAGE_HEIGHT){
        imageHeight = MAX_IMAGE_HEIGHT;
        imageWidth = imageHeight/ratio;
    }
    if(imageWidth > MAX_IMAGE_WIDTH){
        imageWidth = MAX_IMAGE_WIDTH;
        imageHeight = imageWidth*ratio;
    }
    CGFloat yCoord = (self.bounds.size.height - imageHeight) / 2;
    [self.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(10.0f, yCoord, imageWidth, imageHeight)];
    yCoord = (self.bounds.size.height - MAIN_FONT_SIZE) / 2;
    CGPoint point = CGPointMake(10.0 + imageWidth + 10.0, yCoord);
    [self.title drawAtPoint:point
     forWidth:self.bounds.size.width - (10.0 +imageWidth+20.0)
     withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:MAIN_FONT_SIZE]
     minFontSize:MIN_MAIN_FONT_SIZE
     actualFontSize:NULL

     lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail

     baselineAdjustment:UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignBaselines];

}
```

When compiled this issue me about deprecation code on drawAtPoint and suggest that i need to change into DrawInRect ... but I already saw some posts here, even SDK documentation and for my problem i don't know how to manage this ...

Comment: `but I already saw some posts here` where what have you tried

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use drawInRect:withAttributes: instead of drawAtPoint:forWidth:withFont:fontSize:lineBreakMode:baselineAdjustment: in iOS 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19442653/how-to-use-drawinrectwithattributes-instead-of-drawatpointforwidthwithfontf)

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
- (void)drawInRect:(CGRect)rect withAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attrs
```

Instead of

```
[self.title drawAtPoint:point
 forWidth:self.bounds.size.width - (10.0 +imageWidth+20.0)
 withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:MAIN_FONT_SIZE]
 minFontSize:MIN_MAIN_FONT_SIZE
 actualFontSize:NULL
lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail
 baselineAdjustment:UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignBaselines];
```

The size goes in the rect, and the rest of the parameters go as atributes.

Comment: Hello Antonio tkx for response, the problem is rect should be point , what is in fact a point (x,y) ...

Comment: not exactly. You say use drawInRect but everyone can see that from their build warnings. Instead of lazily copy/pasting the API spec, why not provide a concrete example that complements the "Instead of"...